# App won't run on Android 2.3 (Gingerbread)

Tags: android

I have problem running my app on [Android 2.3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Gingerbread) (Gingerbread). The app has a splash screen and timer, and then it runs
the main class. It works fine on [Android 2.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Froyo) (Froyo), [Android 2.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Eclair) (Eclair), etc. It just crashes on Android 2.3.

Do I need to create another thread than the main activity thread?

Here is the error below:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Keep reading farther in your stack trace. You want the lines below "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException". If you are getting this from Eclipse, allow Eclipse to run past the point of the exception, then view the complete stack traces in LogCat (in your DDMS perspective).

Comment: at com.test.example.secondpage.onCreate(secondpage.java:309)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627) /// I got this message off android market. I tried running each class separate, there is no problem, i think i have problem with the main thread taking so long to create thats why its crashing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. It turned out my background image was too big. That’s why my app crashed on create, because it took longer time to load which triggered the UI thread runtimeerror.